# Unknown provider switching from Angular 1.0 to 1.2.3

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to migrate from Angular 1.0 to Angular 1.2.3.  I have added angular-route.js as a dependency and added ngRoute everywhere I believe it should go.  And that is all I've done to move from 1.0 to 1.2.3 I'm getting the following errors:

> Error: Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce <- $route <-
>   ngViewDirective
>
> Error: Circular dependency: ngViewDirective

Here is a snippet of the html where my ng-view is:

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
    <div ng-include src="'application/nav.html'" ng-controller="NavCtrl"></div>
    <div id="content-main" ng-view></div>
</div>
```

So I have controllers above the ng-view directive in the dom. Neither of these controllers have dependency on ngRoute, just $scope and $location.

This works in 1.0 so it has something to do with moving to 1.2.3 but I'm not seeing the issue.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Not certain about this but you may simply have to explicitly include that provider.

Answer (score 12):

In [AngularJS 1.2.1](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/), the `route` module have been pulled out in a single file `angular-route.min.js`, you need to add the reference to this file and `angular-sanitize.min.js` according to the error you posted.

And you need to inject `ngRoute` and `ngSanitize` in the app as well:

```
var app = angular.module('nap.application', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
```

Comment: BTW: This is a well known "issue". A complete list of all changes can be found here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Comment: Tip in case it helps others, you can install angular-sanitize using: bower install angular-sanitize

Answer (score 1):

`$sce` is a security service in AngularJS, are you happening to use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` in any partials being loaded into `ng-vew`?  If so, you need to change those to `ng-bind-html` and include the `ngSanitize` module.